# Foundation Zurb Tabs not working

Tags: zurb-foundation-6

I am not sure as to why this is complex.

1> Load the foundation.css

2> Load the foundation.min.js

3> Add the following code for Foundation Tabs:

```html
<ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="example-tabs">
  <li class="tabs-title is-active"><a href="#panel1" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel2">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="example-tabs">
  <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="panel1">
    <p>Vivamus hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie vehicula. Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel2">
    <p>Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus.  Vivamus hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie vehicula. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor.  Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

4> Initialize foundation and tabs as:

```js
$(document).foundation();

$(document).foundation('tab', 'reflow');
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Your snippet isn't referencing any of the required files (jquery, foundation css and foundation js)

Comment: I thought I covered that on point # 2. I have included the css, default jquery and the foundation.min.js already in my head section.

Comment: Did my answer make sense? If not, please let me know what the problem is.

Comment: I tried the same thing with jsfiddle and it worked on mine too....you pointed me the same thing I got from the foundation's kitchen sink....its just that I have some conflicting css and js in my code it seems. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: No probs. Glad you solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your snippet isn't referencing any of the required files and you're not calling `$(document).foundation();` in the javascript section. Also, you don't need to call `reflow` upon initialization.

You only need the one snippet. You're using multiple snippets and all of the content has been separated, which is why your example is broken.

This is what your code snippet should be like (all of the content is is one snippet):

```js
$(document).foundation();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.1.2/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.1.2/foundation.min.js"></script>

<ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="example-tabs">
  <li class="tabs-title is-active"><a href="#panel1" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel2">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="example-tabs">
  <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="panel1">
    <p>Vivamus hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie vehicula. Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel2">
    <p>Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Vivamus hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie vehicula. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/b7xexjta/)** showing what your snippet should look like.